# is it possible to navigate/move to a different screen by using GestureDetector and class name?

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i have a container that says "lets Get Started"  at the bottom of the introductory screen , is it possible to move the user to login page by detecting the tap and then moving user to the login page by using class name of the login page ?

```
            : GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        print("Container clicked");
      },

      child : Container(

        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: Platform.isIOS ? 70 : 60,
        //-----------------------------------
        //last screen get started box color

        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(
          "GET STARTED NOW",

          style: TextStyle(
            //last screen get started text
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,

          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this for your on tap with login class name

```
onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage())), //your login class name
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass your class name which you want to navigate just replace this class name to **LoginScreen()**

```
             GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("Container clicked");
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen()));
              },
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  "GET STARTED NOW",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: i get the error:              
  error: The method 'LoginPage' isn't defined for the type '_HomeState'.

Comment: @Sam i edited my answer please check again

Comment: @Sam you need to pass your class name to LoginPage() and import the file name on same page

Comment: @Sam you need to import the login page on the top of the _HomeState   
like import "LoginPage.dart"

Comment: thanks Shubham i might be going insane  i am still beginner and somehow ended up removing the imports thanks it works splendidly now